# Bundling multiple rows into 1 transaction

Tags: ajax, sqlite

There's a lot of code here, but I wanted it to be a complete example.  I've taken pains to make it generic so that others can benefit from it as well as benefit from your answer(s).

What I'm trying to do is:

1. SELECT BarcodeID FROM iPad
2. FOR EACH Barcode, upload to the server.
3. FOR EACH Callback, update the iPad

What I need to do is somehow package all the rows up together as a single transaction because right now it is way too slow. Something like:

1. SELECT BarcodeID FROM iPad
2. FOR EACH Barcode, concatenate a JSON string
3. Upload the JSON string to the server.
4. Begin a transaction
5. FOR EACH BarcodeID in the callback
6. commit transaction

```
var Variables = {};

function SelectiPad(SQLTransaction) {
    var local = {};

    local.sqlite = "SELECT BarcodeID"
        + " FROM iPad"
        + " WHERE ServerSyncDateTime is null"
        + " ORDER BY BarcodeID";
    SQLTransaction.executeSql(
         local.sqlite
        ,[]
        ,SelectiPadSuccess
        ,SelectiPadFailure
    )
};

function SelectiPadSuccess(SQLTransaction,SQLResultSet) {
    Variables.iPadRecordcount = SQLResultSet.rows.length;
    for (var i=0; i < SQLResultSet.rows.length;i++) {
        UploadServer(SQLResultSet.rows.item(i));
    }
};
function UploadServer(arg) {
    var local = {};

    local.data = {};
    local.data.method = 'Save';
    local.type = 'post';
    local.data.BarcodeID = arg.BarcodeID;

    local.Promise = $.ajax('Server.cfc',local);
    local.Promise.done(UploadServerDone); // UPDATE Barcode set SyncDateTime
    local.Promise.fail(UploadServerFail);
};
function UploadServerDone(RESULT) {
    var local = {};

    local.ServerSyncDateTime = RESULT.QRY.DATA.SERVERSYNCDATETIME[0]; // UPPERCASE
    local.BarcodeID = RESULT.QRY.DATA.BARCODEID[0]; // UPPERCASE
    local.UpdateiPad = UpdateiPad.bind(this,local);
    dbo.transaction(local.UpdateiPad);
}
function UpdateiPad(arg,SQLTransaction) {
    var local = {};

    local.sqlite = "UPDATE iPad SET"
        + " ServerSyncDateTime=?1"
        + " WHERE BarcodeID=?2"
    SQLTransaction.executeSql(
        local.sqlite
        ,[
             arg.ServerSyncDateTime // 1
            ,arg.BarcodeID // 2
        ]
        ,UpdateiPadSuccess
        ,UpdateiPadFailure
    )
}
function UpdateiPadSuccess() {

    Variables.iPadRecordcount -=1;
    if (!Variables.iPadRecordcount) {
        Finished();
    }
};
function Finished() {
    alert('yay');
}

function SelectiPadFailure(SQLTransaction, SQLError) {
    $('.msg').text(SQLError.message);
    debugger;
}

function UploadServerFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('.msg').html(errorThrown);
    debugger;
}

function UpdateiPadFailure(SQLTransaction,SQLError) {
    $('.msg').html(SQLError.message);
    debugger;
}
```

Comment: I tried formatting it as code, but it doesn't format cleanly on SO for some odd reason.

Comment: So you don't know how to concatenate strings? Or what is your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.dbo = openDatabase('xxx','1.0','xxx', 10000);

(function() {
    var Variables = {};
    Variables.Recordcount = 500;

    dbo.transaction(DropTable);
    function DropTable(SQLTransaction) {
        var local = {};
        local.sqlite = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable";
        SQLTransaction.executeSql(
             local.sqlite
            ,[]
            ,DropTableSuccess
            ,DropTableFailure
        );
    }
    function DropTableSuccess() {
        dbo.transaction(CreateTable);
    }
    function DropTableFailure() {
        debugger;
    }

    function CreateTable(SQLTransaction) {
        var local = {};
        local.sqlite = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable"
            + "(myTableID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
            + ",SyncDateTime Varchar(128)"
            + ");"
        SQLTransaction.executeSql(
             local.sqlite
            ,[]
            ,CreateTableSuccess
            ,CreateTableFailure
        );
    }

    function CreateTableSuccess() {
        dbo.transaction(myTableTransaction);
    }
    function CreateTableFailure() {
        debugger;
    }

    function myTableTransaction(SQLTransaction) {
        var local = {};

        for (local.i=0; local.i < Variables.Recordcount; local.i++) {
            local.InsertSuccess = InsertSuccess.bind(this,local.i);
            local.sqlite = "INSERT INTO myTable(SyncDateTime) VALUES('')"
            SQLTransaction.executeSql(
             local.sqlite
            ,[]
            ,local.InsertSuccess
            ,InsertFailure
            );
        }
    }
    function InsertSuccess(argCurrentRow,SQLTransaction,SQLResultSet) {
        if (argCurrentRow+1 === Variables.Recordcount) {
            alert('Done!');
        }
    }
    function InsertFailure(A,B,C) {
        debugger;
    }
})();


    window.dbo = openDatabase('xxx','1.0','xxx', 10000);

    (function() {
        var Variables = {};

        dbo.transaction(SelectmyTable);
        function SelectmyTable(SQLTransaction) {
            var local = {};
            local.sqlite = "SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY myTableID";
            SQLTransaction.executeSql(
                 local.sqlite
                ,[]
                ,SelectSuccess
                ,SelectFailure
            );
        }
        function SelectSuccess(SQLTransaction,SQLResultSet) {
            var local = {};

            local.data = {};
            local.data.myTableIDs = '';
            Variables.Recordcount = SQLResultSet.rows.length;
            for (local.i = 0; local.i < SQLResultSet.rows.length; local.i++) {
                if (local.i) {
                    local.data.myTableIDs += ',';
                }
                local.data.myTableIDs += SQLResultSet.rows.item(local.i).myTableID;
            }

            local.data.method = 'Save';
            local.dataType = 'text'; // no return value.
            local.done = UploadDone.bind(this,local.data.myTableIDs);
            local.Promise = $.ajax('myTable.cfc',local);
            local.Promise.done(local.done);
            local.Promise.fail(UploadFail);
        };
        function UploadDone(argTableIDs,result,textStatus,jqXHR) {
            var local = {};

            if (result === '') {
                local.UpdateMyTable = UpdateMyTable.bind(this,argTableIDs);
                dbo.transaction(local.UpdateMyTable);
            } else {
                debugger;
            }
        }
        function UpdateMyTable(argTableIDs,SQLTransaction) {
            var local = {};

            local.arr = argTableIDs.split(',');
            local.myDate = yyyymmddhhnnssl();
            for (local.i=0; local.i < local.arr.length; local.i++) {
                local.UpdateSuccess = UpdateSuccess.bind(this,local.i);
                local.sqlite = "UPDATE myTable SET SyncDateTime=? WHERE myTableID=?";
                SQLTransaction.executeSql(
                     local.sqlite
                    ,[
                     local.myDate
                    ,local.arr[local.i]
                    ]
                    ,local.UpdateSuccess
                    ,UpdateFailure
                );
            }
        }
        function UpdateSuccess(argCounter,A,B,C) {
            if (argCounter+1 === Variables.Recordcount) {
                alert('done!');
            }
        }
        function SelectFailure(A,B,C) {
            debugger;
        };
        function UploadFail(A,B,C) {
            debugger;
        }
        function UpdateFailure(A,B,C) {
            debugger;
        }
    })();
```